# Using Adobe Acrobat API in .net 5 and C#, how do we create pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, acrobat, .net-5

I am using ".net 5.0" and C#.   I may write a windows service (batch job) to accomplish the following tasks. I prefer to work directly with the Adobe Acrobat API rather than the third-party API like GrapeCity. The main reason is licensing complexity.

1. I need to read some data stored in the database and create a .pdf file.
2. I need to use a pdf template document and fill those fields and save the pdf.
3. I have a document template in word. I need to fill those fields and save them as a pdf document.

On the Adobe site, I noticed,

1. Document Service SDK (Cloud Based) and provides the following APIs

   - PDF Tools API
   - PDF Embed API
2. Acrobat SDK
3. PDF Library SDK

What should be my desired path of development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF Library SDK if your budget allows it. But when it comes to "licensing complexity" most 3rd party solutions will offer you far simpler licensing.

Comment: You make perfect sense. The pricing is too complex and prohibitively expensive compared to general cloud-based APIs.